# Starting Google Chrome in application mode

Tags: google-chrome

How do I start Google Chrome in application mode?

What I want is to surf to a website, such as `www.facebook.com`, directly without borders or address bar, etc.

Comment: **Note** The answer changes over time, as this feature changes.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[The easiest way](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710) is to browse to the website in Chrome, and then follow these steps:

1. Click the Chrome menu button (`⋮` or `☰`)
2. Select `More tools` → `Add to desktop...`
3. Edit the name if you wish, and click `OK`

Alternatively, in earlier versions of Chrome:

1. Click the page menu.

   [image]
2. Select `Tools` → `Create application shortcuts`.
3. In the Gears dialog box, select the checkboxes for the locations where you want shortcuts to be placed.
4. Click OK.

---

The other way is from the command line:

```
"path\to\chrome\chrome.exe" --app=http://facebook.com
```

Comment: Looks like easiest way change since this was initially posted and requires a change in chrome flags now : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3A5ZTe-HrVE

Comment: stackoverflow [Run standalone web app in Google Chrome without borders or toolbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229235/run-standalone-web-app-in-google-chrome-without-borders-or-toolbars) has an answer which suggests using the `--kiosk http://example.com/` option when starting Chrome rather than `--app`.

Comment: It seems that if an existing Chrome session is running, the `--app` option is ignored.

Comment: Also, can you explain the 'page menu'? Right-clicking on a page in Chrome 53 under Linux brings up a menu, but it doesn't have a 'Tools' or 'Create application shortcuts' option.

Comment: @MichaelScheper This answer needs updating methinks.  In Chromium 53, go to main menu (three vertical dots) -> More tools -> Add to desktop...

Comment: @piedar: Thanks. I've edited the answer. I'm surprised that you couldn't, since I only have slightly more rep than you on this site, but perhaps it's my rep elsewhere that allows me to edit.

Comment: @MichaelScheper My edit was [rejected](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/579163), apparently because it "deviates from the intent" of the original.  So the answer remains obsolete.  Fantastic.

Comment: @piedar, just FYI, edits can be used to update an answer as a supplement to the original answer (and it doesn't hurt to cite a reference in the edit comment so the reviewer can verify it).  The problem with your edit was you replaced the answer.

Comment: @piedar: I suggest you try editing it again, leaving the original answer this time (even though not many people would find the outdated information useful). The additional notes you included look useful.

Comment: @MichaelScheper On Windows it also says "Add to desktop..." so I don't think my platform notes are actually necessary.  Nice one with the Unicode dots - much better than hotlinking to Google's image server.

Comment: **OUTDATED**------------

Comment: In the Windows 10 we can use "start chrome --app=https://google.com"  in Linux "chromium --app=https://google.com"
They work nicely. Does anyone know for Mac?

Comment: The -app feature is working great but I can't seem to do it manually. However, Chrome allows you to add website shortcuts "as an app" and it is brilliant. https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en

Answer (score 13):

As of Chrome 67, it has changed again. The following works in Chrome 70:

1. Click the Chrome menu button (`⋮` or `☰`)
2. Select `More tools` → `Create shortcut...`
3. Go to `chrome://apps` and find your new shortcut
4. Right-click on icon, and select “Open as window”
5. *Optional* Right-click again, and select `Create shortcuts...` to create desktop or menu icons.

Comment: **Note**: `--app` doesn’t have the same behavior.

Comment: indeed  `--app=path/to/etc`  just removes tabs and buttons, while the above really creates an app with specific options. There are other differences. I'll post a complementary answer.

Answer (score 10):

On windows with chrome 73, I can get app mode in the presence of existing chrome windows complete with extensions running like this:

```
chrome.exe --app=https://duckduckgo.com --new-window
```

Without --new-window, the --app argument is ignored if there is a running instance of chrome already.

Comment: "Without --new-window, the --app argument is ignored if there is a running instance of chrome already." this may not be the case anymore.  At least, I didn't need the `new-window` argument on ubuntu just now, with a running chrome open.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1369692/1039759)  mentioning two different ways of creating  an "app".

---

**The first method is to create a shortcut with the `--app-id` parameter**

For a Google app like Youtube, go to `chrome://apps/`, right click the icon and select "Create  shortcuts"

[image]

For any page, go to that page and — under the menu button, *More tools > Create shortcut*:

[image: with --app-id]

The shortcut to the desktop contains the following command (testing in Linux with Chromium browser):

```
path/to/chromium-browser "--profile-directory=Profile 1" --app-id=bojccfnmcnekjgjhcaklmcgofnngpjcl
```

The result is something closer to a separate app with integrated buttons for back/history, refresh, extensions (if installed) and a few other options:

[image]

Only basic options are available, like print and find, an option to start the normal window of the browser and also an option to "Uninstall Google Docs", which deletes the app shortcut:

[image]

---

**The second method is to create a shortcut with the `--app` parameter**

Using a shortcut with a command like

```
path/to/chromium-browser "--profile-directory=Profile 1" --app=https://docs.google.com/document
```

we get a page stripped of tabs and buttons.

[image]

The extensions associated with a specific profile are running in background (if that profile was used to sign in), but ***no browser settings are accessible*** unless they are related to the page address itself (e.g. if that is a Goggle page like Googles Docs, you will be able to access profiles and Google apps. Clicking a Google app icon will open that app in the main window of the browser).

[image]

Other settings will have to be made through a normal window (or an app-like window created by the `--app-id` argument).

Comment: icon is blurry when launching google-chrome with --app flag on linux

Answer (score 2):

If you are on mac it is a little more involved; however Lifehacker has an article with a script that I just checked (May 9, 2013) and it works.

http://lifehacker.com/5611711/create-application-shortcuts-in-google-chrome-for-mac-with-a-shell-script

Comment: The guides downloads are gone

Answer (score 1):

1. unhide "extension for known file types" from 
   File Explorer Options -> View
2. create .bat file
3. cd (your chrome.exe file)

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

chrome.exe --app=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpsI6OAwLno

here you some info about it
https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

and maybe more 
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

in the end there are a lot of flag you can pull, chose as you like