# Launch Chrome in a Fixed Sized Window

Tags: google-chrome, launcher

I am trying to launch Google Chrome in a fixed sized window, in application mode.

I have read the following question, and have changed the desktop icon to start in application mode.
[Starting Google Chrome in application mode](https://superuser.com/questions/33548/how-to-start-chrome-in-application-mode)

What I am unable to do however, is to launch the application at a fixed width and height, and ideally without the min and max buttons enabled.

I am running on Windows, and using the following switches

chrome.exe --new-window --app=http://myserver/MyApp/

Comment: What OS are you on? A lot of OSs (linux and MacOS in particular) have utilities that allow you to resize windows and such.

Comment: running on Windows XP SP3.