# How to hide chrome warning after crash?

Tags: google-chrome, crash, session-restore

When Chrome has crashed, it displays a warning (under the address bar) upon restart, offering to restore tabs. I'm launching chrome in kiosk mode and I don't want theses warnings to be displayed.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: This is a probable duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/461035/disable-google-chrome-session-restore-functionality. Even though this question is older, it has 10x fewer views and 3x fewer votes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should run Chrome in Incognito Mode with this command:

```
chrome --incognito --kiosk http://127.0.0.1
```

[Here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6f47751b1f9d8179&hl=en) they talk about running this command before starting Chrome to stop the Restore Bar from appearing:

```
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly": true/' \
    ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
```

Comment: incognito does the trick for me.

Comment: Yes, incognito works, but it disables cookies and cache, and (in my case) they are required.

Comment: I added the sed line in my cron file after @reboot

Comment: For me in Chrome 74 it seems to have moved to a different file and no longer has  white space, but this worked: `sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' "$HOME/.config/google-chrome/Local State"`

Comment: For me in Chrome 108 I get the "Restore pages? Chrome did not shut down correctly" dialog; I look in `$HOME/.config/google-chrome/Local State` and `exited_cleanly` is true.

Answer (score 24):

Based on [@MiQUEL's answer](https://superuser.com/a/864918/4160) to [this duplicate question](https://superuser.com/q/461035/4160):

There are a few approaches.

Incognito mode (`--incognito`) helps, but it has several disadvantages, such as disabling the cache.

Passing `--disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble` works in some versions of Chrome, but, as of Chrome 58, it no longer works.  (Removing the `--disable-session-crashed-bubble` was done as part of [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=653287); comments there suggest that the flag was intended to test the bubble feature and was not intended as an end-user feature to hide the Chrome warning).

The most reliable approach I've found is to manually edit Chrome's on-disk preferences.  Here's how you do this on Linux.  (Note that these instructions are for chromium-browser; Google Chrome itself uses `~/.config/google-chrome` instead of `~/.config/chromium`.)

```
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' ~/.config/chromium/'Local State'
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/; s/"exit_type":"[^"]\+"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
```

Putting it all together with a couple of additional flags that have been helpful for kiosk mode in one Chrome version or another:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' ~/.config/chromium/'Local State'
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/; s/"exit_type":"[^"]\+"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
chromium-browser --kiosk --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble "http://some_url/"
```

Comment: For some reasons tilde wasn't resolved for me, I had to use $HOME in I use lxsession autostart.

Answer (score 12):

--disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble

```
while true; do
   chromium-browser --kiosk http://fotolia.com/ --no-first-run --touch-events=enabled --fast --fast-start --disable-popup-blocking --disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-tab-switcher --disable-translate --enable-low-res-tiling
   sleep 10s;
done
```

Comment: Confirmed, this works for me on Chromium 47 on Linux.

Comment: Did the trick for me. My Chromium ignored the "exited_cleanly" Preferences.

Comment: doesn't work anymore (Chromium 65 on RaspberryPi)

Answer (score 8):

This *finally* worked for me, and it's pretty simple:

1. Shut down Chromium gracefully
2. Change the "Change content" permissions of ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences to "Nobody"

That will lock the state of two variables, regardless of how Chromium
was shut down:

- "exit_type": "Normal"
- "exited_cleanly": true

Of course, only do that after you're done setting preferences

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Repeated admonishments from moderator aside, unlike every other suggested solution for this problem, this one actually worked for me. So thank you for sharing it.

Comment: This seemed like a great solution at first glance. The main problem is that when using this with WebDriver under Selenium, chromedriver complains (at least on a Windows node) that it can't write to the prefs file at startup, so it won't let you launch a session when the prefs file is read-only.

Comment: +1 thanks for this. The command I used to lock the file: `sudo chattr +i ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`

Answer (score 4):

I believe `--restore-last-session` will also do the job.

Source: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: actually in that page it says `Note that this does not force automatic session restore following a crash`.

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to solve this problem for days. Incognito mode comes without cache, and changing Preferences file did not work for me.

Finally I have been able to solve by following steps below:

1. Go to `chrome://flags` url. Search for “Enable session restore bubble UI” and set it to Disabled.
2. open chrome with `--kiosk --disable-infobars` options.

Comment: Looks like that flag no longer exists

Answer (score 2):

`--restore-last-session` argument when launching Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux I prevent the crash dialog by removing write access to the "Local State" file in the user profile.

Actually I run many instances of chrome with different user profile folders. Sometimes I run a script to kill all chrome processes for cleanup purposes. I used to get the annoying dialogs at restart and fixed it this way:

```
find /somepath/profiles/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "Local State" -exec chmod -w '{}' \;

pkill -9 chrome

find /somepath/profiles/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "Local State" -exec chmod +w '{}' \;
```

If you want to prevent the dialog after an uncontrolled crash, maybe you should remove write access for good. I don't know if it can have negative consequences though, never tried that.

Comment: what is the command to remove write access to the stupid chromium, I tried resetting both variables in that Preferences file I hard boot (repower) my Raspberry pi, I keep getting this nasty popup.  I also tried the --disable-session-crashed-bubble in the pi autostart when launching chromium.  Thanks. cd ~/.config/chromium/Default
then what

Comment: @Meryan isn't my example working for you? Maybe with chmod a-w instead of just -w?

Comment: So after exiting manually from Chrome via Ctrl-F4
I greped the json and it shows both exit flags as Normal/true

I ran chmod -w ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences 
went back to the Pi launched Chromium from the GUI. Than hit the power switch on reboot I still get the popup.
I am unix novice I don't understand your script /somepath/profiles/ that is apply to me as well? I have only the default user on the raspberry pi

Comment: chromium is somehow able to change the access rights on the Preferences file.  I see the access writes are back as 
-rw------ instead of -r--------- after the chmod -w

Comment: I run chromium from the pi autostart as follows:
chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --disable-session-crashed-bubble  --kiosk  http mydomain.com

Comment: The file that I set to readonly is called "Local State" (yes, with a space) and resides in the user profile folder. If you don't know where your user profile folder is, then start chrome with a specific user profile folder: --user-data-dir=/some/folder/here

Comment: Tried chmod -w ~/.config/chromium/'Local State'  after cleaning, chromium has super power it changes it to -rw----------------------------

I have now posted my wasted time here
https://superuser.com/questions/1640618/how-to-disable-permanently-the-chromium-popup-after-crash-or-hard-boot

Comment: Maybe you can start chromium with a different user that has less privileges?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1643107/690627
This brute force worked but I hate it when a simple command line option would have sufficed.  I am still in the midst of fine tuning things so having to unlock these files is unpleasant.
I have no idea why sed from the autostart modifying Preferences and "Local State" does not work on /home/pi/...  what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a current answer, I found the following tip on stackexchange that worked for me:
chromium-browser --kiosk --app=http://your.url.here

Answer (score 0):

Finally something that seems to work and ignore the crash (caused by powering the pi instead of a shutdown/restart).

The --app= seems to do the trick from the pi autostart file.

```
chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --kiosk  --app=http://mumti.org/?ch=MUMTI&cat=SLOWTV
```

--app mentioned here
[Starting Google Chrome in application mode](https://superuser.com/questions/33548/starting-google-chrome-in-application-mode)

One of my previous failed attempts was using sed from the autostart to modify Preferences and "Local State".  I have no idea why it did not work on /home/pi/

The last successful solution was
https://superuser.com/a/1643107/690627 although this brute force worked I hated it because

1. a simple chromium command line option would have sufficed.
2. I am still in the midst of fine tuning things so having to unlock these files is unpleasant.
3. locking files is probably a bad idea as it may crash chromium