# Disable Google Chrome session restore functionality

Tags: google-chrome, restore, kiosk

Chrome offers to restore the last session when it did not shutdown properly (power outage, Chrome crashed, ...).

How do I disable that? (Setting or command line switch)

I'm using a batch file that starts (among other things) chrome in kiosk mode for a single page on windows startup. Even after power outage etc. it should only launch that page without the ruckus.

Comment: It might not be possible to disable it.  If you are using a batch file, I would simple delete the file that handles the session, before you launch Chrome.

Comment: @Ramhound Which file(s) would that be? "User Data\Default\Current Session" and "User Data\Default\Current Session" don't seem to make a difference. Neither does "User Data\chrome_shutdown_ms.txt".

Comment: @riha simply clearing history and sessions before closing the browser will solve your problem and there were some third party tools which would automatically wipe history when your system is restarted

Comment: A power outage prevents clearing history / sessions. Deleting the whole profile folder works, but that feels like a bit too much...

Comment: @janot and other closevoters: this question is more highly upvoted and has a lot more views than the linked duplicate. I've voted to close the older, less-viewed one as a duplicate.

Comment: @ncdownpat I guess thats because most people search for "chrome disable session restore", not "chrome crash warning" or the like. At least that's why I created a new question back then - I didn't find the other one. Anyhow, my first gold badge =)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I know this is old but I thought it would be helpful to others that may come across this.

I had this issue and tried the flags settings but that did not help. adding `--incognito` to the command did resolve the issue.

```
chrome.exe --kiosk --incognito some.web.site
```

I tried this in various fashions of crashing Chrome and pulling the power to the PC. In all tests the system would power up and go into kiosk mode without the frown face error message.

Comment: Is this any different than @Dom's answer?

Comment: note, incognito mode disables caching, so if that's important for your application this is not a great option.

Comment: This disables any extensions you have set up.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen Not necessary, you can enable extensions in incognito mode.

Answer (score 31):

try this line (old)

```
chrome.exe --kiosk --disable-session-crashed-bubble "http://example.com"
```

(new)

```
chrome.exe --kiosk --hide-crash-restore-bubble "http://example.com"
```

For more detailed information

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#hide-crash-restore-bubble

Comment: this works well if you include --disable-infobars which then kills the warning alltogether

Comment: As of now `chrome.exe --disable-session-crashed-bubble` is just enough to put the prompt away.

Comment: note that this does'nt work with Chrome 58 anymore

Comment: Yes, --disable-session-crashed-bubble seems to be non-operational, feel free to add your two bits to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=445256#c17 to let the Chromium team know this matters.

Comment: With Chrome 71: `--restore-last-session` argument when launching chrome

Answer (score 28):

I see some inconveniences in the solutions provided:

--incognito switch removes cache, what is pretty bad in most circumstances.

(Copy-pasting chrome help )

> Google  Chrome has hundreds of undocumented command-line flags that are added and removed at the whim of the  developers.

--disable-session-crashed-bubble depends of which version of chrome are you using, the most actual version v39 doesn't have this setting allowed.

The solution I did was to alter the user profile and overwrite the crash status to a normal close status, It's a simple hack that works perfect.

This is the script I run in kiosk-mode in a chrome-only session under Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly": true/' ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type": "Crashed"/"exit_type": "None"/' ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
google-chrome --kiosk "http://some_url"
```

It simply finds and replace the string

- "exited_cleanly":false
- exit_type": "Crashed"

with

- "exited_cleanly": true
- "exit_type": "None"

So, no matter how chrome has closed. It will always think it has closed gracefully.
**(Tested in many chrome versions)**

Comment: If I had used linux back then, I would've probably given this a try.

Comment: This slightly modified command works with Chromium 56:
sed -i -e 's/\("exit_type":\s*\)"Crashed"/\1"None"/g' \
  -e 's/\("exited_cleanly":\s*\)false/\1true/g' \
  ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

Comment: Don't forget about the `chromium/Local State` file, which has the same field.

Comment: I put an updated answer, based on this information, at https://superuser.com/a/1206120/4160.

Comment: My version of Chrome (60.0.3112.101) uses a minimized json blob with no spaces between key and value ala `"exit_type":"Crashed"`, so the sed command should handle either

Comment: To make it handle either do something like this:
sed -i 's/"exit_type": *"Crashed"/"exit_type": "None"/' ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
That will handle any number of spaces between the key and values (including none).

Answer (score 14):

Try this

- go to `chrome://flags/`
- then click `Enable` on the link that writes: "`Disable Better session restore`"

I hope this helps

Comment: Looks like they removed this flag... (Windows Chrome v38), bummer.

Answer (score 4):

Open chrome \ Default \ Preference, and change the value to

*"exit_type": "none",*

"exited_cleanly": true,

Save the file, and put him to attribute "read only".
Tested on various versions of the Chrome browser

Comment: On Chrome 72 `"exit_type": "Normal"` appears to be the preferred value.

Answer (score 3):

Someone has suggested just running Chrome in Incognito mode to get around the problem [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/WSK1J_Y_TvY%5B1-25%5D). If you are running in full screen mode and redirecting to a specific page that shouldn't be noticeable. I know that's a bit of a work around.

Comment: That certainly provides some helpful info, thanks. My current workaround is to delete the whole profile folder before starting chrome. Incognito is probably the better choice. I'll report back.

Comment: note, incognito mode disables caching, so if that's important for your application this is not a great option.

Comment: Yes choosing incognito results in a different popup annoyance because it will prompt to allow target/desired site to store some data over and over and over.