# Run a browser in fullscreen without any other UI elements (like translate, restore session, e.t.c.)

Tags: linux, browser, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to set up a Raspberry-Pi as a very light-weight/simple monitoring solution. All it has to do is open up a web-page on boot.

Opening the web-page was easy enough. I simply put a desktop file into `~/.config/autostart` with a command like:

```
chromium-browser --kiosk http://192.168.1.23/monitor.html
```

So far so good. There are two problems however:

1. I see a toolbar stating "This page is in German. Would you like to translate it?
2. When I unplug the R-Pi and re-plug it I get the yellow "restore session" toolbar.

I cannot figure out a way to fix this. I tried with `--temp-session` hoping the "restore session" would go away. Unfortunately it did not :(

I also tried with `--app` which did not change a thing.

Any idea how to fix that? Note that I am not fixed on chromium. It just happens to be the one browser I found which makes it easy to launch in fullscreen with a URL in once simple command.

Comment: How are you powering it down, just switching off the power? That might corrupt the filesystem, unless it's all read-only or entirely in ram.

Comment: It's on a journaled FS so that shouldn't really be a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to add the two flags `--disable-translate and --incognito`

`chromium-browser --disable-translate --kiosk --incognito http://192.168.1.23/monitor.html`

Incognito mode is a funny way to make Chromium not worry about the last session when it restores from a crash.

References:
[Disable Google Chrome session restore functionality](https://superuser.com/questions/461035/disable-google-chrome-session-restore-functionality)

[Chrome command line switches from a conversation on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149610/how-to-override-default-set-of-chrome-command-line-switches-in-selenium)

Comment: Interesting. `--disable-translate` was not listed in `--help` :)

Answer (score 2):

(putting this as answer because i cant comment)

As of chromium version 60.0.3112.89, --disable-translate doesn't work anymore.

The workaround, if you have access, is to remove the lang from html tag or set it to "en".

**UPDATE**:

As of version 69, the previous workaround doesn't work anymore, the solution is to add this tag to the html head:
`<meta name="google" content="notranslate">`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've upvoted you, and with luck you may comment now ;) Not sure how much is needed...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Unfortunately not. The project I originally needed this for is no longer in production.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm that this is not working anymore with Chromium 71.