# chrome: "not shutdown correctly" message

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to run Google Chrome as a kiosk application. I.e. nobody should know that it's an browser. As such, the computer that it runs on can be turned off by maintenance people or power out tage. When it comes back again, it'll show the "not shutdown correctly" message. How do I disable it from being shown?

Comment: See [Disable Google Chrome session restore functionality](http://superuser.com/q/461035), which I think should also work in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Google Chrome session restore functionality](http://superuser.com/questions/461035/disable-google-chrome-session-restore-functionality)