# Start Chrome from Command Line without restore warning

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

We have an automation setup, where we need to start Google Chrome (v98) from the Command Line. We do that via the following command:

```
chrome <website-url> --start-maximized
```

This works well under normal circumstances, but if Chrome crashed in the last session, you get a warning, asking if you want to restore the previous session, which we never do.

[image: Chrome restore prompt]

Sorry prompt being in danish, but I guess you know what I'm talking about.

I have Googled the issue and found lots of potential flags you can add, but I haven't found any that works. Here are some of them:

- `--disable-session-crashed-bubble`
- `--new-window`
- `--restore-last-session`
- `--incoginito`

The only one that works with the current version of Chrome (98) is `--incognito`. But since we need plugins, this is not a viable solution. I have found some solutions which involves [editing the Preferences file](https://superuser.com/a/864918/919317).

But are there really no simpler solution? There was a working flag once it seems, why isn't there one now? Or some other way to reset it with a simple command?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this docs](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), maybe

- `--hide-crash-restore-bubble`
- `--restore-last-session`

could work.