# Google Chrome always says, "Google Chrome was not shut down properly"

Tags: google-chrome

I am having this problem from over a month now, no matter how nicely I shut down Google Chrome and then shut down my system, every time that I lauch Google Chrome again, it shows this message:

> Google Chrome was not shut down properly

What's wrong? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5):

This was just happening to me too. I found inside this file "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences" near the bottom of the file (inside the Profile section) this line:

> "exit_type": "Crashed"

Once I modified the line to read "normal" instead of "Crashed" like this:

> "exit_type": "normal",

The problem disappeared.

Comment: This appears to have worked for me but we'll see if it's a permanent fix.

Answer (score 3):

Couple potential problems and fixes. Firstly check Chrome isn't sitting in your Windows taskbar (bottom right). If it is:

Right-click > Uncheck "Run Chrome in the background"

Additionally to this you might want to have a look in your `msconfig` just to see if Chrome is booting on startup.

Could be a problem with an extension. Turn them off via `chrome://extensions/` and see if this solves it. Should this be the issue simply turn them back on one at a time till you find the culprit.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ctaf-ZXcvag)

See if either of these solves it.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, I have had exactly the same problem for quite a while now. REALLY annoying.
For me, Chrome even started two separate instances, one of them showing the error, the other one behaving normally.

I managed to fix it by going to Settings / Advanced Settings and turning OFF the "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" option (found this in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/697618/getting-google-chrome-didnt-shut-down-correctly-every-week) thread, suggested by Ashtangakasha)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that Chrome, unlike 99% of all Windows programs, fails to shut down properly if Windows is shut down while a Chrome browser window is open.

I have tried both checking and unchecking "Continue running programs in background" which did not fix the problem.

I have tried disabling all extensions which also did not work.

In between all these attempts I was careful to "Restore" Chrome, if the error appeared, shut down the browser and reboot, before making another attempt to shutdown with browser open.

I am an IT professional with more than ten years experience.  I find this one of the most annoying bugs in the history of software.

By the way, the suggestion to modify the Preferences file, only "fixes" the problem until the next time you shut down Windows with the Chrome browser still open.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome and Chromium write exit status into Preferences file. When it starts it writes Preferences file with:
 **"exited_cleanly": false**

and upon clean exit writes Preferences file with:
 **"exited_cleanly": true**

To prevent message about unclean shut down make sure that you have **"exited_cleanly": true** written in your Preferences file

On my Linux kiosk running on Raspberry Pi this sed command line added to /etc/rc.local fixes issue permanently:

> sed -i 's/exited_cleanly\":\ false/exited_cleanly\":\ true/g'
>   /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

Answer (score 0):

After editing this file

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
```

with `"exit_type": "normal"`.

Click right on file "Preferences" and check read only. For me, the file was rewritten with "crashed" on restart. It's ok if you don't want to change your chrome settings for home automation use, it's perfect