# Very simple and small portable browser for web application

Tags: browser

I am developing a web application for localhost use (using Server2Go) and want to pack it with the browser application.

I've tried a lot of browsers; TheWorld browser is good but it has the Internet Explorer core.

I'm looking for a really small and simple browser but not Internet Explorer-based - it should be compatible with all standards.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using windows, there's a few options. You can use [chrome in application mode](https://superuser.com/questions/33548/how-to-start-chrome-in-application-mode) - possibly with a portable version of some sort, or [mozilla prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) - one uses the chrome engine, the other gecko.

Prism hasn't been updated in a while so in future, you might want to replace it with [chromeless](http://mozillalabs.com/chromeless/) once its ready.

Comment: Thank you! Chromelese is what I'm looking for! :) Nice...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Pokki](http://pokki.com). Looks very promising.

Comment: Pokki is very interesting ... but chromelese will be better choice ... but maybe in future I will choose pokki ... anyway thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: @JaL sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Server2go](http://download.cnet.com/Server2Go/3000-10254_4-10414377.html) with [google chrome portable in application mode](https://superuser.com/questions/33548/how-to-start-chrome-in-application-mode). Very nice one click system.

Answer (score 0):

QTweb (http://www.qtweb.net/qtweb.html) is a very light Webkit-based cross-platform and portable browser, it can be very easily customised to become chromeless (using the .ini file with the executable, it's an interesting option for desktop-like app)