# Launching Chrome with no toolbars and a predefined website

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to launch Chrome with everything disabled except the web view (No toolbars, menu options etc.) and have it load a predefined website?  It would be preferable if I could control the size of the window as well.

I don't think the Chrome Kiosk mode will help because if I understand correctly it will run full screen and prevent other use of the computer while it's running.

I recall seeing some web-based app load Chrome this way but I'm not sure what to look for.

Scenario:  I've got a Foscam security camera which I view/control via a web browser.  I thought it'd be convenient to have a shortcut on my desktop which would launch Chrome and directly load the camera, in a small window with no other obstractions in the view.

Comment: I know what you mean. I'd start researching pop-up windows.  Maybe create an html file and call it as a popup? I'm thinking there will be some Javascript involved; probably a few lines of code to it.

Comment: Look at chrome app mode

Comment: Thanks @Zalmy, seems to be what I'm looking for, at least the closest I can get to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Select `More tools` (or `tools` depending on your Chrome version) from your Chrome Menu button → `Add to desktop...` or `Create application shortcuts`

Otherwise, if you don't need it to be fully automated, run the shortcut and press F11 but it will always be in fullscreen mode, unfortunately.

### Source

[Here](https://superuser.com/a/33553/868402) is where I found this information.

Answer (score 0):

create shortcut or run the following command replacing YourURL with the one you want.

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window --app=http://www.YourURL
```